# Calling complicated C++ functions in Python (linux)

Tags: c++, python, linux

I have some functions in C++ source, declared like this:

```
extern "C" {
    int32_t comp_ip_long(const std::vector<EachColumn>& in, std::vector<EachColumn>& out);
}
```

The C++ code is compiled into xxx.so (linux shared object) and I want to call the function in Python. notice that I cannot modify the C++ code, so something like `boost::python` is not accessable.

I've tried ctypes.CDLL, but I don't know how to pass the complicated argument to xxx.so?

PS:

I've given a .so with some functions (with the above parameter type, but function names are unknown), the function name and parameters are input by user.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need helper glue functions declared as `extern "C"` to construct (i.e. initialize) and fill your `std::vector<EachColumn>` and have these helper functions called from Python.

Perhaps

```
typedef std::vector<EachColumn> columnvect_t;
extern "C" columnvect_t *new_vect() 
    { return new columnvect_t; };
extern "C" void del_vect(columnvect_t*vec) 
   { delete vec; };
extern "C" void pushback_vect(columnvect_t* vec, EachColumn* col) 
   { vec->push_back(*col); };
```

and likewise for your `EachColumn` class.

<sup>Maybe you need to make a glue library linked to the C++ library and `dlopen`-ed by Python</sup>

Basically, Python is more C friendly than C++ friendly (so you need to make C++ glue code feeling like C for Python). Be careful that no C++ exception throwing crosses the Python interpreter (so catch all of them inside your glue functions)

If the C or C++ code is huge, you might consider customizing GCC to perhaps help in generating such glue code, either with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) or with D.Malcom's [GCC python Plugin](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/gcc-python-plugin.git/). But this takes time.

Comment: You still have to add C++ code. In fact the function names are provided by others and I don't know it at all..

Answer (score 1):

You can't call it from ctypes, you need at least to warp the function inside C so you could call it from Python.

I don't know the details of your function but for example if you have such this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
  int bar;
public:
  Foo(int bar) : bar(bar) {}

  int getBar() const {
    return bar;
  }

  void setBar(int bar) {
    this->bar = bar;
  }

  void doSomething() const {
    std::cout << bar << std::endl;
  }
};
```

you can warp int this way:

```
// previous code here +
#define CAST_FOO(x) (static_cast<Foo *>(x))

#ifndef FOO_DEBUG
extern "C" {
#endif

void* foo_new(int bar) {
  return static_cast<void*>(new Foo(bar));
}

int foo_get_bar(void *foo) {
  return CAST_FOO(foo)->getBar();
}

void foo_set_bar(void *foo, int bar) {
  CAST_FOO(foo)->setBar(bar);
}
void foo_do_something(void* foo) {
  CAST_FOO(foo)->doSomething();
}

void foo_destroy(void* foo) {
  delete CAST_FOO(foo);
}

#ifndef FOO_DEBUG
};
#endif

#ifdef FOO_DEBUG
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  void* foo = foo_new(10);

  foo_do_something(foo);
  foo_set_bar(foo, 20);
  foo_do_something(foo);

  foo_destroy(foo);

  return 0;
}
#endif
```

now it should be callable from ctypes, and from C also.

```
$ g++ -Wall foo.cpp -DFOO_DEBUG
$ ./a.out
10
20
$ g++ -Wall foo.cpp -shared -o foo.so
$ python
>>> from ctypes import *
>>>
>>> so = cdll.LoadLibrary('foo.so')
>>> foo = so.foo_new(10)
>>>
>>> so.foo_do_something(foo)
10
>>> so.foo_set_bar(foo, 20)
>>> so.foo_do_something(foo)
20
>>> so.foo_destroy(foo)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more work but maybe worth it in the long run is to use [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/index.html)

Example taken from the boost documentation:

Following C/C++ tradition, let's start with the "hello, world". A C++ Function:

```
char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}
```

can be exposed to Python by writing a Boost.Python wrapper:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

That's it. We're done. We can now build this as a shared library. The resulting DLL is now visible to Python. Here's a sample Python session:

```
>>> import hello_ext
>>> print hello_ext.greet()
hello, world
```