# How to call C++ functions of a class from a Python

Tags: python, c++, function, word-wrap

I tried with the link: [Calling C/C++ from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python), but I am not able to do the same, here I have problem of declaring extern "C".so please suggest suppose I have the function called 'function.cpp' and I have to call this function in the python code. function.cpp is:

```
int max(int num1, int num2) 
 {
  // local variable declaration
  int result;

  if (num1 > num2)
    result = num1;
  else
    result = num2;

  return result; 
 }
```

Then how i can call this function in python, as I am new for c++. I heard about the 'cython' but I have no idea about it.

Comment: Check [boost python library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/reference.html)

Comment: Just use python's [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)

Comment: @clcto  actually i have another big code for ADC which is in c++, but i am using python for coding, so I have to call that c++ code in python. The above c++ function is just example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you use C++, disable name mangling using `extern "C"` (or `max` will be exported into some weird name like `_Z3maxii`):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
int max(int num1, int num2) 
{
  // local variable declaration
  int result;

  if (num1 > num2)
    result = num1;
  else
    result = num2;

  return result; 
}
```

Compile it into some DLL or shared object:

```
g++ -Wall test.cpp -shared -o test.dll # or -o test.so
```

now you can call it using [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html):

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>>
>>> cmax = cdll.LoadLibrary('./test.dll').max
>>> cmax.argtypes = [c_int, c_int] # arguments types
>>> cmax.restype = c_int           # return type, or None if void
>>>
>>> cmax(4, 7)
7
>>>
```

Comment: Can you please tell, what will be changes if I have classes in c++ and I have to call that in python

Comment: @Latik It's not possible to use C++ classes with `ctypes` without creating C wrapper like in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590465/calling-complicated-c-functions-in-python-linux/18591226#18591226). You can also choose to use SWIG, which makes it much easier to wrap C++ classes into Python classes, [SWIG Basics](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIG.html#SWIG), [SWIG and Python](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python).

Comment: thnx for help, the above your given solution is working in Ubuntu  but it is not working in Raspberry Pi as it has Raspbian OS. It is giving error as `AttributeError: ./test.dll: undefined symbol: max` please give any solution.